# Imprimir relatório do ReportViewer diretamente, sem pré-visualização

Tags: c#, webforms, impressão, reportviewer, reporting-services

Preciso enviar um relatório diretamente para a impressora, sem pré-visualização ou geração de PDF.

O problema é que a aplicação é **Web Forms** e todas as soluções que encontrei até agora fornecem suporte somente para Windows Forms, ou seja, a aplicação acaba buscando a impressora instalada no servidor de aplicação, em vez da impressora do browser do cliente.

Segue código do Report Viewer:

```cs
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials(_user, _password, _domain);
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(_reportUrl);
reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report";
reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(ConfigureParameters());
reportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;

var file = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Caso alguém saiba alguma forma de transformar o PDF gerado pelo Report Viewer em uma impressão, também seria muito útil.

Comment: cara, direto para a impressora eu nunca mandei, pois desenvolvo em web, mas tenho uma função que salva em pdf

Comment: A minha função também já salva em PDF. O problema é que a aplicação não pode baixar o pdf, pois é a obrigatória a impressão deste relatório. Vou procurar uma forma de enviar esse pdf direto pra impressora.

Comment: tenta dar uma olhada nesse link, se não me engano já fiz algo do tipo http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598424/How-to-Silently-Print-PDFs-using-Adobe-Reader-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, eu uso o seguinte código para gerar o PDF

```
       LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();
        relatorio.EnableExternalImages = true;

        relatorio.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Financeiro/NotaFiscalEletronica/Danfe/NotaFiscalEletronicaDanfeReport.rdlc");


        ReportParameter codigoBarrasParameter = new ReportParameter();
        codigoBarrasParameter.Name = "CodigoBarras";
        string codeBarArquivo = String.Format(@"file://{0}\{1}-codBarras.png", this.CaminhoXML, chaveAcesso);
        codigoBarrasParameter.Values.Add(codeBarArquivo);
        relatorio.SetParameters(codigoBarrasParameter);

        DanfeReports nfeReport = new DanfeReports();

        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("IdeDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaIdentificacao(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("EmiDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaEmitente(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DestDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaDestinatario(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ValTotDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaValoresTotais(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("TranspDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaInformacoesTransporte(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ProdSevDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaProdutoServico(chaveAcesso)));
        relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("InfAdicDataSet", nfeReport.NotaFiscalEletronicaInformacoesAdicionais(chaveAcesso)));

        string reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] bytes;

        //Renderiza o relatório em bytes
        bytes = relatorio.Render(
            reportType,
            null,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string arquivo = String.Format("{0}.pdf", chaveAcesso);

        SaveMemoryStream(this.CaminhoXML, arquivo, memoryStream);`

        public bool SaveMemoryStream(string caminho, string nomeArquivo, MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(caminho))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho);

        FileStream file = new FileStream(caminho + @"\" + nomeArquivo, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        byte[] bytes2 = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(bytes2, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        file.Write(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
        file.Close();
        memoryStream.Close();


        return true;
    }`
```

Acredito que seja só tu pegar o PDF e mandar o comando para a impressora.

Comment: O que ele quer saber é como "mandar o comando para a impressora".