# Impressão do windows forms com reportviewer direto na impressora

Tags: c#, winforms, impressão, reportviewer

Tenho uma aplicação feita em `windows forms` e `reportviewer`, o meu problema está na impressão:

> preciso mandar imprimir direto na impressora sem ter que abrir a caixa de seleção para selecionar a impressora

Como fazer isso em `c#`?

```
    private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintReport();
    }

    public void PrintReport()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(txtVolume.Text); i++)
        {
            this.EtqTransportePSTableAdapter.Fill_EtqPS(this.EtqTransportePSDataSet.EtqTransportePS, txtNota.Text);
            this.reportViewer1.PrintDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Seria interessante você postar parte do código que já fez, desta forma poderemos indicar com base nisso a melhor solução para seu problema.

Comment: Verifique se esse post não lhe serve (se já não viu). http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43561/imprimir-relat%C3%B3rio-do-reportviewer-diretamente-sem-pr%C3%A9-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o e por favor, edite sua pergunta acrescentando o código que colocou como comentário.

Comment: Opa Ismael obrigado pela atenção, mas ja vi este post sim e não me ajudou ainda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vamos lá... no meu caso eu fiz imprimindo em um impressora matricial.. melhor maneira que encontrei foi usando String Bilder..

Codigo de impressão

```
private void PrencherArquivo(DataTable dt, NotaFiscal item, ClienteAG cliente)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(((char)27).ToString()).Append("C").AppendLine(((char)18).ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("");
    sb.AppendLine("");
    sb.AppendLine("");
    sb.AppendLine("");
    for (int i = 1; i <= item.volqte; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(cliente.nome);
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine(cliente.logradouro + "-" + cliente.numeroendereco);
        sb.AppendLine(cliente.bairro + "-" + cliente.mun_ufd_sigla);
        sb.AppendLine("CEP:" + cliente.cep);
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine(item.numero + "                  " + item.volpeso.ToString("N1"));
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.AppendLine("            VOLUME " + i + " DE " + item.volqte);
        if (item.volqte > i)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("");
        }
    }
    sb.Append(((char)27).ToString()).AppendLine("@");
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("EPSON LX-300+ /II", sb.ToString());
}
```

Codigo da impressão.

```
public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
{
    IntPtr pBytes;
    Int32 dwCount;
    // How many characters are in the string?
    dwCount = szString.Length;
    // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
    // the string to ANSI text.
    pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
    // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
    SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realiza a impressão automática local do arquivo.

```
public ActionResult ImprimeDocumento(string caminho)//Caminho onde está seu arquivo
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(caminho))
        {

            try
            {
                myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("Nome da sua impressora");

                Process process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                     {
                         CreateNoWindow = true,
                         Verb = "print",
                         FileName = caminho,
                     },
                };
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
        return null;

    }
```